# Capturing geotagged text notes for field work?

Tags: software-recommendations, geotag, iphone

I'm looking for a smartphone application that will allow me to take notes at a site in the field and associate each note with a geotag (like photos) of the current location which I can then later import in to GIS software.

What options do I have?

Comment: If you have ArcGIS, then [Collector for ArcGIS](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/) is an easy way to take field notes and bring them right into ArcGIS.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of proprietary options available, including: 1) [ArcGIS Cllector](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/collector/); 2) [GIS Cloud](http://www.giscloud.com/); 3) [Fulcrum](http://fulcrumapp.com/).

For a "free" solution, Google's "My Maps" app for Android is really good for point collection, but the app itself does not allow you to attached images (to my knowledge). However, you can attach images from the web application, so you could theoretically survey your points, take your pictures, and then attach the photos to each point. This could work for a few dozen points, but might be difficult if you're collecting hundreds of points.

Comment: Definitely second using Fulcrum. I've had personal experience using Fulcrum. A team of us (3) conducted a systematic social observation study in a favela in Brazil. Together, we were able to collect close to 700 data points- each point included a survey, photos, field notes. Data collection errors were easily corrected while on the ground.